# Is there a way to set a device id using pyserial?

Tags: python, qt, serial-port, embedded

I want to use a serial port emulator like comm0comm and then write a python script to simulate a device transmitting data. My Qt GUI application can then connect to the other virtual serial port and test using the simulated data.

I have managed this already, although in my application I want to scan the serial ports for a device with a particular ID, and then connect to the relevant port. Is there anyway I can set a device serial number using pySerial? Or are there any other suggestions for how to do this?

```
bool foundDevice = false;
foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortinfo, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
    qDebug() << "Checking port " << serialPortinfo.serialNumber();
    if (serialPortinfo.serialNumber() == m_deviceSerialNumber) {
        qDebug() << "Found device";
        connectPort(serialPortinfo.portName());
        foundDevice = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: A serial connection does support vendor IDs, product IDs or serial numbers of the connected devices. These information are usually taken from the USB to serial bridge built into the device. You have to check the USB tree for them.

Comment: @KlausD. The OP is asking how to set the id, not how to read it. And the answer is no, there is no way.

Comment: You are talking about scanning the serial ports for a device with a particular ID, do you mean the vendor/product ID's from USB? I don't understand why you want to SET a device serial number, and what do you understand under serial number (USB, PCI, ...)?

Comment: @jeb the Qt Serial Port API gives access to serial numbers, I have updated the question with some code. For example, I want to automate the testing of that code